# Dimensions for a website background image

Tags: image, aspect-ratio, picasa

I am confused in deciding the dimensions for a background image for my website. I am creating a collage like image in picasa and it defines the image dimensions using aspect ratios. If I want to create an image of 2048 x 1800, what aspect ratio should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2048/1800) gives the exact result 256/225, so an aspect ratio of 256:225 is correct. (Of course, a more inexact value would be 1.14:1, which would give you something like 2052x1800.)

Answer (score 0):

As the aspect ratio is the ratio of the width of the image to its height, the aspect ratio of 2048x1800 image is 1.14:1 (2048/1800 = 1.14).

Comment: Unfortunately, SO didn't allow me to put infinite number of 7s in my answer so I had to round the result.